# Close popup on submit and display results in parent window

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts

How do I display results in parent window when a button is clicked on the child window(popup window)?

I have a jsp page. When I click a button on this page, it goes and fetches a list(***studentList***) of Student objects and displays only their first name in a
pop up window as follows.

A Student object has all the informations such as first name, last name, birth date, address etc.

There are checkboxes next to each name.

```
Jack    Tom     Paige
Julie   Hank    Red
Frank   Tina    May
```

What I want to be able to do is when I check the check box(es) and click a button in popup, I want to close the pop up window and 
display all the details about the students selected in the parent window.

When displaying the student details, I intend to get the students details from the list of students(***studentLists***) that I already have instead of running a
query against the database.

I am using Struts 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If domain of parent window and child window are same then you can access parent window using `window.opener`. using window.opener you can call parent window methods.

parent window:

```
window.childwindowAction = function(arg1, arg2,....){

   //  do stuff
};
```

child window

```
window.opener.childwindowAction (arg2, arg2, ..);
```